# If two tangents can be drawn to different tangents of a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{1}-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ from the point $(a,a^2)$, then find range of $a$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, solution-verification, conic-sections

The equation of tangent for hyperbola is

$$y=mx\pm \sqrt {a^2m^2-b^2}$$

$$a^2=ma\pm \sqrt {m^2-4}$$
$$a^4+m^2a^2-2a^3m=m^2-4$$
$$a^4+m^2(a^2-1)-2a^3m+4=0$$

There will be two distinct values of $m$

$$4a^6-4(a^2-1)(a^4+4)>0$$
$$a^6-a^6-4a^2+a^4+4>0$$
$$a^4-4a^2+4>0$$
$$(a^2-2)^2>0$$
$$a^2>2$$ Or 
$$a^2<2$$

But the given answer for it is $a\in (-\infty, -2)\cup (2,\infty)$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $(a,a^2)$ lie on $y=x^2$. Now draw diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct

Let me verify by a separate method

We know two  distinct tangents can be drawn for any point $P$ if it lies outside the hyperbola

So, we need $$\dfrac{a^2}1-\dfrac{a^4}4-1<0$$

$$\iff a^4-4a^2+4>0$$

$$\iff(a^2-2)^2>0$$ which is true if $a^2-2\ne0$ and real

Comment: Are you sure? What happens for $a=1$ for example?

Comment: @Micheal, At $a=1,m$ has one finite value and the other value is not finite, right?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I saw that the second value is not valid. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning works for $a^2\neq1$.

But for $a^2=1$ we obtain $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$,  and they are  valid!

Answer (score 0):

With the given solution, I believe that the problem statement should read: “If two tangents can be drawn to different *branches* of a hyperbola...” This requires the $x$-coordinates of the tangency points to have opposite signs, and this indeed occurs for $a\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$.

If you’re reproducing the problem statement correctly here, then there must be a typo in the original.